# unknown standard deviation = range/4

Tags: standard-deviation, sample

Suppose you want to estimate the average age of all Boeing 737-300 airplanes now in active domestic U.S. service. You want to be 95% confident, and you want your estimate to be within one year of the actual figure. The 737-300 was first placed in service about 24 years ago, but you believe that no active 737-300s in the U.S. domestic fleet are more than 20 years old. How large of a sample should you take?

Solution says that E = 1 year, the z value for 95% is 1.96, and s is unknown, so it must be estimated by using s approximately equals to (1/4) * (range). As the range of ages is 0 to 20 years, s = (1/4)(20) = 5

Why do we use 1/4 * range for standard deviation ?

Answer (score 3):

This is what's known as the range rule of thumb. It's shortcut method for getting an approximate standard deviation when the range of values (max-min) is known. [Here's](https://www.thoughtco.com/range-rule-for-standard-deviation-3126231) a short article on it.

The reasoning behind it is that in a normal distribution, about 95% of data points lie within two standard deviations around the mean - so, this rule of thumb basically assumes that the data sample falls inside that 95% interval, which is 4 standard deviations wide; hence, one standard deviation is 1/4th of that range.